# Download grid view and some text into a excel in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, data-binding, gridview

I am binding data to a grid view.

```
 string MysqlStatement = "SELECT TimeReceived,TimeRead, Concat(FirstName,', ',LastName) as Name FROM tbl_usermessage INNER JOIN tbl_user on tbl_usermessage.UserID = tbl_user.UserID WHERE MsgID = @Value1";
        using (DataServer server = new DataServer())
        {
            MySqlParameter[] param = new MySqlParameter[1];
            param[0] = new MySqlParameter("@value1", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            param[0].Value = MessageID;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", MessageID);
            ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, MysqlStatement, param);
        }

        Grid_UserTable.DataSource = ds;
        Grid_UserTable.DataBind();
```

I am binding data to a repeater list,

```
string MysqlStatement = "SELECT Title, RespondBy, ExpiresBy, OwnerName, Concat(LowTarget,' - ',TopTarget) as Threshold FROM tbl_message WHERE MsgID = @Value1";
        using (DataServer server = new DataServer())
        {
            MySqlParameter[] param = new MySqlParameter[1];
            param[0] = new MySqlParameter("@value1", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            param[0].Value = MessageID;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", MessageID);
            ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, MysqlStatement, param);
        }
        rptList.DataSource = ds;
        rptList.DataBind();
```

I have a button to download the report

```
protected void btn_ExcelDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string path = Server.MapPath("");
        path = path + @"\Resources\MessageStatus.xlsx";
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);


      Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
      Response.ContentType = "Application/msexcel";
      Response.WriteFile(path);
      Response.End();

    }
```

I tried few things and managed to download the excel sheet from the button click, but How can I fill all the data from the repeater list and grid view. I haven't done this before pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Foo</th>
                        <th>Bar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>Whatever <%# Container.DataItem %></td>
                    <td>Stuff <%# Container.DataItem %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Sample code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Repeater1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            Repeater1.RenderControl(writer);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.xlsx");
            Response.ContentType = "Application/msexcel";
            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
```